# Не выводит в metabox все данные пользователя (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Написал хук, который создает метабокс с выводом данных пользователя. Прописал в функции , как написано в документации (https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_userdata):

```
function metatest_showup($post, $box) {
    $user_info = get_userdata(1);

    echo 'Имя пользователя: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
    echo 'Имя пользователя: ' . $user_info->user_firstname . "\n";
    echo 'Имя пользователя: ' . $user_info->user_lastname . "\n";
    echo 'Уровень доступа: ' . $user_info->user_email . "\n";
}
```

Логин выводит, email выводит, а firstname и lastname нет. Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что не так?

См [документацию](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/):

```
 $first_name = $user_info->first_name;
 $last_name = $user_info->last_name;
```

А не `user_ххх`

Comment: большой код, я написал часть в вопросе, с которой возникли сложности....Ваша версия сработала, спасибо Вам, буду дальше разбираться почему мой вариант у меня не работал....возможно просто что-то не доглядел, еще раз спасибо